# address already in use with redis-server

Tags: server, terminal, redis, redis-server

When running the redis server, it shows address already in use
This is the stacktrace:

```
45546:C 12 Jul 2019 10:04:41.888 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
45546:C 12 Jul 2019 10:04:41.888 # Redis version=5.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=45546, just started
45546:C 12 Jul 2019 10:04:41.888 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
45546:M 12 Jul 2019 10:04:41.889 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
45546:M 12 Jul 2019 10:04:41.890 # Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem shows that the port is already in use by another process or is open in another window.

**Change the port of redis server**

`redis-server --port 6360` will start a Redis server listening to port 6360.

`redis-cli -p 6360` - Now use this to make your client listen at this port.

Hope this helps solve your problem

Comment: hi @Rajan, yes that really helps! but when i tried to do ```redis-cli -p 6360 ``` . it threw back ```Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6360: Connection refused
not connected> redis-cli -p 6360``` what would you think the problem is? :)

Comment: did the redis server start successfully on that port? start a fresh terminal and run the redis cli command.It works fine for me.Are you trying to connect through a program?

Answer (score 2):

**Rajan Sharma**'s answer is great and works fine, but if you wondering how to make this work with **supervisord** check here: [redis-server-ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04).

You can use Rajan's answer but it's better to change the port in redis config file, lacated: /etc/redis/redis.conf, example using nano editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

and locate this line:

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379 (IANA #815344).
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
port 6379
```

and change port number to what you want, example 6360 as above and save ti.
Then restart the redis service:

```
sudo systemctl restart redis.service
```

Finally check the redis service is active:

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @Ranjan will work,

If you want to debug further and see which process is using that port can be done by below

```
netstat -antp | grep 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make new copy of.config files and change the port and use that file**

I have faced this issue when I was using Redis in windows.
And the root cause was when I have installed Redis from a msi installer it created a service which kept running in background and I was not aware of that.

So when ever I try to start this service manully with default config I got the same error but after creating a new copy of config file with l changed port it worked for me.